# approve function not working while trying to add Liquidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap, pancakeswap, defi

I have a created a pair of DAI ([0x8e60C2Ab51Ea0dB31208F11FDc35CF30372eCE0a](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x8e60C2Ab51Ea0dB31208F11FDc35CF30372eCE0a#code)) and BUSD ([0xe33a84F08326fdbcb4b6511eDEb90868113569dB](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xe33a84F08326fdbcb4b6511eDEb90868113569dB#code)) on BSC Testnet. The contracts are also verified there. I want to create a liquidity pool using this pair. Before calling the addLiquidity function, the approve function is called but my script gives the following error, even though the DAI contract already has an approve function:

```
TypeError: token1.approve is not a function
    at module.exports (E:\Blockchain\Defi\Seaworld\AddLiquidity\scripts\deploypool.js:54:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

This is my code. I have commented out the calls to createPair function as pair has already been created.

```
try {
    const [admin, _] = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const factory = await Factory.at('0x26df448c993a51fee6e0079a9fcf9331dd47b788');
    const router = await Router.at('0x4e5779b686f1ff27fc6fd88d592986c5c6669e5d');
    const token1 = await Token1.at('0x8e60C2Ab51Ea0dB31208F11FDc35CF30372eCE0a');
    const token2 = await Token2.at('0xe33a84F08326fdbcb4b6511eDEb90868113569dB');
    // const pairAddress = await factory.createPair.call(token1.address, token2.address);
    // const tx = await factory.createPair(token1.address, token2.address);
    await token1.approve(router.address, BigNumber.from(amount).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))));
    await token2.approve(router.address, BigNumber.from(amount).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18)))); 
    await router.addLiquidity(
      token1.address,
      token2.address,
      BigNumber.from(amount).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))),
      BigNumber.from(amount).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))),
      BigNumber.from(amount).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))),
      BigNumber.from(amount).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))),
      admin,
      Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10
    );
```

What is the issue over here? The script works when I test it with other contracts.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const busdAbi = [
    "event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value)",
    "function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)"
  ];

  // retrieve the BUSD contract
  busdToken = await ethers.getContractAt(busdAbi, BUSD_ADDRESS?BUSD_ADDRESS:'', deployer)
```